# Is it possible to have IP whitelisting using google GCP API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

I've been searching on google and keep getting referred to the VPC documentation https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/set-up-private-connectivity but I don't think this will solve my problem. I'm trying to limit the IP address accessing my webhook function on GCP and I need to use API gateway (Apigee isn't an option at the moment for me). Any advice would be great!

Comment: Is API Gateway a strong requirement?

Comment: Well, I need something before the webhook function to stop any traffic from coming in. Putting code to whitelist within the function isn't an option either. Would using an API key work to whitelist IP addresses? I'm really new to this, thanks for responding :)

Comment: The question is if you can restrict traffic to your backend by IP? Like to tell API Gateway to allow only incoming connections from a certain IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If API Gateway isn't requirement, I propose you this solution:

- Update the [ingress control of your function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) to set it `internal_and_cloud_load_balancing` to allow only traffic from your VPCs and the load balancers
- Then create a [HTTPS external load balancer with a serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) that point to your Cloud Functions
- Add [Cloud Armor policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#examples) on your Load Balancer to filter IP sources.

Comment: Thanks for offering this solution! I think i'm going to try using an API key first and restrict the IP address and see where that leads me first, but it's great to have another solution to try as well :)